# Google BigQuery - Execute dynamically generated queries from a select statement

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Have a huge table in Google BigQuery with following structure (> 100 million rows):

```
name | departments
abc  | 1,2,5,6
xyz  | 4,5
pqr  | 3,4,6
```

Want to convert the data into following format:

```
name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
abc  | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 | 1
xyz  |   |   |   | 1 | 1 |
pqr  |   |   | 1 | 1 |   | 1
```

As of now, able to generate the queries required to prepare the dataset in this format by using CONCAT and REGEX_REPLACE functions:

```
    SELECT ' insert into dataset.output ( name, ' + 
  CONCAT(
      '_' , replace(departments,',',',_')  ) 
      
   + ' ) values(  \'' + name +'\','+ REGEXP_REPLACE(departments, "([^,\n]+)", "1") +')'
FROM (
select name, departments from dataset.input )
```

This generates the output with the 100 M insert queries which can be used to create the data in the required structure.

However, now below are my questions:

1. **Can we execute the output of this query (100 M insert queries) directly by using Big Query SQL or we would need to fire each insert one by one?**
2. I believe there is no way to pivoting or transposing the data in a column with multiple comma separated values. Is that right?
3. Is there a more optimal way of achieving this using BigQuery SQL and not writing custom Java code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' name, '1,2,5,6' departments UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '4,5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pqr', '3,4,6' 
)
SELECT 
  name,
  IF(departments LIKE '%1%', 1, 0) AS d1,
  IF(departments LIKE '%2%', 1, 0) AS d2,
  IF(departments LIKE '%3%', 1, 0) AS d3,
  IF(departments LIKE '%4%', 1, 0) AS d4,
  IF(departments LIKE '%5%', 1, 0) AS d5,
  IF(departments LIKE '%6%', 1, 0) AS d6
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```sql
Row name    d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6   
1   abc     1   1   0   0   1   1    
2   xyz     0   0   0   1   1   0    
3   pqr     0   0   1   1   0   1
```

So you need to run above with destination to whatever new table you prepared

Note, above assumes you have just 6 departments and most important there is no ambiguity in numbers like 1 does not conflict with 10 for example
If you do have such case - you need transform below lines

```sql
  IF(departments LIKE '%2%', 1, 0) AS d2,
```

into

```sql
  IF(CONCAT(',', departments, ',') LIKE '%,2,%', 1, 0) AS d2 ...
```

And of course, you can use just one simple INSERT statement

```sql
INSERT `project.dataset.new_table` (name, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)    
SELECT 
  name,
  IF(departments LIKE '%1%', 1, 0) AS d1,
  IF(departments LIKE '%2%', 1, 0) AS d2,
  IF(departments LIKE '%3%', 1, 0) AS d3,
  IF(departments LIKE '%4%', 1, 0) AS d4,
  IF(departments LIKE '%5%', 1, 0) AS d5,
  IF(departments LIKE '%6%', 1, 0) AS d6
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

So, the final point of all this is:
instead of generating INSERT STATEMENT for each and every row in original table - you should generate simple SELECT statement that does "pivoting"

> Update for "extreme" minimizing generated code

See an example:

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION c(departments STRING, department INT64) AS (
  IF(departments LIKE CONCAT('%',CAST(department AS STRING),'%'), 1, 0)
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' name, '1,2,5,6' departments UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '4,5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pqr', '3,4,6' 
), temp AS (
  SELECT name, departments AS d
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
SELECT 
name,
c(d,1)d1,
c(d,2)d2,
c(d,3)d3,
c(d,4)d4,
c(d,5)d5,
c(d,6)d6
FROM temp
```

as you can see - now each of your 10000 lines will be like `c(d,N)dN,` with max in length as `c(d,10000)d10000,` so you have chance to fit into query size limit

Comment: Hi Mikhail, Thanks for prompt response. Actually the number of unique department ids can be ~10000 . Therefore was not sure if we can dynamically generate this SELECT query in the JAVA program. Are there any limitations to this approach with such a huge number of expected columns?

Comment: there is a limitation for number of columns and size of row that you need to fit in

Comment: As per our understanding, Google BigQuery supports upto 10000 columns

Comment: i have answered few quite similar questions on dynamically generating pivot queries - you should search on SO. As long as you don't exceed limits  - you should be good. Note: yet another limit is size of query text. Note: 10000 columns is definitely quite extreme case and sounds suspicious design wise - you might want to check if/why you even need to do this

Comment: Thanks once again Mikhail. Will go through these and revert back in case of any further questions. We need these many number of columns due to the kind of data processing use case we are trying to serve.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, after trying generating the query for 10000 department ids, it fails in the console with the error that "Query is too large and the limit is 256KB" BigQuery doc says unresolved query limit is 256 KB and resolved query limit is 12 MB. The query that we generated is 600 KB in size

Comment: see in my previous comment note about limit on size of query text :o) try to minimize the size of query by let's say shortening names, eliminating redundant elements, spaces, etc. just try :o)

Comment: did try to minimize it but it is difficult beyond a point as you see that if we have 10000 department ids, we will need 10000 lines like "IF(CONCAT(',', departments, ',') LIKE '%,2,%', 1, 0) AS d2" :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176282/discussion-between-dragon-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: see update in my answer  - hope it will help you to minimize query and get inside the size limits

Comment: Hi Mikhail, It reduced the size by more than 1/4. Should work for numeric ids mostly. Will see how we can handle alphanumeric ids as that will increase the size considerably. Having said that, thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: sure, no problem :o)